# Weird Entity Expansion Case

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, expansion

I am currently dealing with a rather weird case of entity expansion problem.

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
    XMLReader xmlReader = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileReader("input.xml"));
    SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
```

Code is taken from http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/preventing-entity-expansion-attacks-in.html. I am using similar code in my application. Now when I feed xml like

```
<!DOCTYPE lolz [
<!ENTITY lol "lol">
<!ELEMENT lolz (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY lol1 "&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;">
<!ENTITY lol2 "&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;">
<!ENTITY lol3 "&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;">
<!ENTITY lol4 "&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;">
<!ENTITY lol5 "&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;">
<!ENTITY lol6 "&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;">
<!ENTITY lol7 "&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;">
<!ENTITY lol8 "&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;">
<!ENTITY lol9 "&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;">
]>
```

I get "The parser has encountered more than "64,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException"
which is expected behavior. I catch it and handle gracefully. However, our testing team produced this example

```
    <!DOCTYPE lolz [
<!ENTITY lul "lulllullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullullul">
  ]>

 <someTag>&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;&lul;  </someTag>
```

well the original lines are much longer :) Anyway, when I feed this type of xml, the app does not crash, but the CPU usage becomes unacceptably high and no exception is thrown. 
Is there any way I can prevent this? Setting certain limits?

Comment: Surely a single element with 15 entity expansions isn't causing high CPU load, and I've tried a line with 30,000 expansions without noticing anything remarkable. If you don't describe your use case in more detail, one cannot even begin to reason about possible causes. - Anyway, there's no reason an exception to be thrown, and you can slow down many an application with excessive impact on string handling caused by O(n²) reallocation effort.

Comment: well, it is far more than 30,000. I am trying to find if there is a way to limit general entity size for example. I know that system works properly, but it is not acceptable in my case. I need to find a way to isolate this cases and stop the app before it takes entire cpu